# Map is shown without buildings

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm looking for rendering 3D Buildings extrusion in a React-Native app using github /mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl

I created a custom map in MapBox Studio,added the following line into the style.json and uploaded the map in Mapbox Studio

```
{
    "id": "buildings",
    "type": "fill-extrusion",
    "source": "composite",
    "source-layer": "building",
    "minzoom": 15,
    "filter": [
        "all",
        [
            "==",
            "extrude",
            "true"
        ],
        [
            ">",
            "height",
            1
        ]
    ],
    "paint": {
        "fill-extrusion-color": "hsl(206, 7%, 61%)",
        "fill-extrusion-height": {
            "type": "identity",
            "property": "height"
        },
        "fill-extrusion-base": {
            "type": "identity",
            "property": "min_height"
        },
        "fill-extrusion-opacity": 1,
        "fill-extrusion-translate-anchor": "viewport"
    }
}
```

The buildings are rendered as expected in mapbox-studio but when I go back in my React-Native App the map is shown but without the buildings.

Do you guys have any idea about how to display buildings in 3D with the react-native-mapbox-gl sdk ?

Thanks.

[Screenshot of mapbox studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCfd3.png)
[Screenshot of the React-Native Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdEpu.png)

Comment: 3D buildings are only supported in the most recent iOS and Android releases. You'll have to upgrade the version of the bindings you're using if you're not on the most recent version.

Comment: @mollymerp Hi, thanks for your anwser, everything seems up to date, i'm using react-native-mapbox-gl v.5.2.0 and using the data buildings from Mapbox Streets V7 in MapBox Studio, do you have a clue ?

Comment: did you got solution? I am also looking for the same

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari, can you please try my answer and tell me fix it solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

**Compatibility fix for this issue:**

1. Add a new layer for your custom map in *Mapbox Studio*

   - **Source**: Mapbox Streets V7 (building)
   - **Type**: Fill extrusion
2. Edit style
   Click on **Height** and then Edit JSON (in the bottom of the panel)

[image: Edit JSON information]

Then, paste the following code:

```
{
  "type": "identity",
  "property": "height"
}
```

3. Paste and publish your style and use as a MapBox style for your map in React-Native

Comment: I got solution for react native. Actual react native mapbox accept expression in different way not like mapbox gl js. Your code is for mapbox gl js.